# Getting discord.py bot to only process dms from certain role

Tags: python, discord.py

Hey there I am incredibly new to coding in python I have a little bot written that takes dms and outputs them into a certain channel with a simple ignore function for user ids if they get banned from the server so they cannot message anymore. I was wondering if there was a way I could add to the code a way for the bot to only receive dms from a role.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user or message.author.id in ignoreusers:
        return
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        channel = bot.get_channel(1118363617654472805)
        await channel.send(f"{message.author} sent:\n{message.content}")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

I don't even know where to begin

Answer (score 1):

You can make a condition with discord.utils to do an specific action only if  the sender has that role. Here in my example, I'm validating if the user that sent the message has the role "MOD".

```
role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="MOD")
if role in message.author.roles:
      Do something
    else:
    Do something else
```

Comment: Apologies for me being so stupid but I've tried slotting in this example where I think it would go however upon dm from someone it spits out an error.

`role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Member")
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'`

Comment: DM's are not part of a guild (server), so you can't access a server role like that.
You need to define the guild (server) and the  channel ID where you want to forward the DM messages.

Once the guild is defined, you could get if the person has a role in that server. 

**channel = bot.get_channel(your channel ID) 
 guild = bot.get_guild(your guild)**